# Vue router does not route to my pages - It returns cannot get /home

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, quasar-framework

My routes array looks like this

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: () => import('layouts/MainLayout.vue'),
        children: [{ path: '', component: () => import('pages/Index.vue') }],
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        component: () => import('pages/Home.vue'),
    },

    // Always leave this as last one,
    // but you can also remove it
    {
        path: '*',
        component: () => import('pages/Error404.vue'),
    },
];
```

But when I navigate to home it says `cannot GET /home`.
I'm using quasar btw, if that helps.

Comment: is it an spa ? if its the case can you share your backend code ?,,, if not can you tell me how do route ? are you passing it in the url field ?

Comment: @HijenHEK Yes it is in SPA. I have no backend, just static frontend. I created it using quasar cli

Comment: check my answer ,, history mode it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### History mode

first make sure you are using [history mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html) so you can access routes like /home directly . if history mode is not activated you will have a `#` thats hash_mode wich is default in vuejs

**vue router example**

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```

### Only frontend Routes

second in case of an spa that is loaded from a route like laravel make sure your backend is not redirecting users to any other page than the root `/` and all the routing should be handeled only buy your frontend .

**laravel web.php example**

```
Route::get('{path}', function () {
    return view('app');
})->where('path', '.*');
```

### Not an spa ?

if this is not an spa then you need to use hash mode ( remove history mode) , and access vue routes using the hashed url syntax

**example hash urls**

- `https://myspa.com/#/`   for the MainLayout.vue
- `https://myspa.com/#/home` for the pages/Index.vue

Answer (score 0):

Try to use '/home' in your home route

```
{
    path: '/home',
    component: () => import('pages/Home.vue'),
},
```